# why does this error "LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib.obj" occur when I compiled a c project which created from ECPG file

Tags: postgresql, apache-age, ecpg

I was trying to compile a c project in visual studio which generated by ECPG file then I got this error
`LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib.obj`
even though I added this line `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib` in **Additional Dependencies** in addtion to this  line `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\include` in **Additional Include Directories**

I tried to open **Additional Dependencies** to change
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib`
To
`"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib"`
but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

this is not the correct way to link a library in VScode

go to Project `Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.` and add the name of the library you want to link

finally, make sure that you are configuring it in the correct platform (x86 or x64)

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio linker is unable to locate the required PostgreSQL library files, which results in the error "LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:Program FilesPostgreSQL14lib.obj".

- Verify the Visual Studio settings are right, double-check the **path** to the 'lib' directory, and look for security involvement or problems with **file permissions**.
- Consider using **environment variables** as well to indicate the proper locations.